# Converter tabela HTML5 + imagens para CSV ou SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, html5, microsoft-excel, tabela-html

Estou com um grande problema!

Tenho basicamente 1 milhão e meio de registros incluindo imagens em uma tabela em HTML5 (já começa aí, o navegador não renderiza todas as imagens).

Minha ideia era converter essa tabela para CSV, e assim, jogar para um banco de dados MySQL, e logo criar um algoritmo de páginas de exibição.

Como eu posso realizar essa conversão, das tags `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, alguns `<a>` e também `<img>` para um arquivo do Excel?

Existe alguma outra alternativa? Segue exemplo de como é um resumo" de cada linha da tabela:

```
<tr>
    <td class="">
        <a href="#">Processo 2333382</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a>
            <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a>
            <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a>
            <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Resumindo, preciso passar todos os links de imagens com o número do processo para o banco de dados, ou antes, para um arquivo CSV.

Comment: Queres passar para um CSV porque achas melhor ou porque precisas de ter um CSV?

Comment: É uma das formas em que achei para poder enviar essa tabela depois para o MySQL, mas ter alguma forma que já faça isso direto, é justo.

Comment: Creio que a utilização de PHP para um html5 parser seria a melhor opção.

Answer (score 3):

Você não especificou qual a saída esperada, então estou supondo que, para o seguinte arquivo de entrada *input.html*:

```
<tr>
    <td class=""> <a href="#">Processo 1</a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""> <a href="#">Processo 2</a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
</tr>
```

A saída produzida é um arquivo csv *output.csv* no seguinte formato:

```
 Processo 1,LINK DA IMAGEM,LINK DA IMAGEM,LINK DA IMAGEM
 Processo 2,LINK DA IMAGEM,LINK DA IMAGEM,LINK DA IMAGEM
```

O script em python abaixo faz essa conversão:

```
from lxml import html
import csv

# Le a entrada e salva em s
with open('input.html', 'r') as myfile:
        s = myfile.read()

# Faz o parse e encontra todas as linhas da tabela (<tr>)
page = html.fromstring(s)
rows = page.findall('tr')

# Extrai o conteúdo do html
data = []
for row in rows:
    datarow = []
    for c in row.getchildren():
        # Se for uma imagem, salva o link
        imgel = c.find('a/img')
        if imgel is not None: 
            datarow.append(imgel.get('src'))
        # Se não for uma imagem, salva o texto (nome do processo)
        else:
            datarow.append(c.text_content())
    data.append(datarow)

# Escreve a saída em um arquivo csv
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    for row in data:
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA

Para realizar isto no Excel VBA com Regex.

### Regex

O código é: `(?:<a.*?>\s*[<img src="]*)(.+?)(?="?>?\s*(?:<\/a>|$))`

O link da validação no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ozShMU/2/) e o [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/r-mMwHwniV07miZZ)

```js
const regex = /(?:<a.*?>\s*[<img src="]*)(.+?)(?="?>?\s*(?:<\/a>|$))/g;
const str = `<tr>
    <td class=""> <a href="#">Processo 1</a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> 
</a> 
</td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class=""> <a href="#">Processo 2</a> </td>
    <td>
 <a>
 <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
    <td> <a> <img src="LINK DA IMAGEM"> </a> </td>
</tr>
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

### Habilitar Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)

   2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
   3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
   4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

### Código VBA

Basta manipular a variável str para inserir a string desejada no Excel, pode ser uma célula do Excel, Range, Array ou simplesmente textos, como no exemplo.

Este código não realiza tudo o que foi desejado, porém sugiro que divida o problema em vários problemas menores e tente montar o código que realiza a tarefa desejada.

```
Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
str = "<tr> <td class=""""> <a href=""#"">Processo 1</a> </td> <td> <a> <img src=""LINK DA IMAGEM""> </a> </td>  <td> <a> <img src=""LINK DA IMAGEM""></a></td>    <td> <a> <img src=""LINK DA IMAGEM""> </a> </td></tr><tr>    <td class=""""> <a href=""#"">Processo 2</a> </td><td> <a> <img src=""LINK DA IMAGEM""> </a> </td>    <td> <a> <img src=""LINK DA IMAGEM""> </a> </td>    <td> <a> <img src=""LINK DA IMAGEM""> </a> </td></tr>"
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'New regexp
objRegExp.Pattern = "(?:<a.*?>\s*[<img src=""]*)(.+?)(?=""?>?\s*(?:<\/a>|$))"
objRegExp.Global = True
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    For Each m In objMatches
        Debug.Print m.Submatches(0); Value
    Next
End If
```

### Resultado

Utilizando a String do @klaus

[image: Resultado]